# Annihilator of a projective cover

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative finite dimensional algebra and $M$ and $P(M)$ be respectively a finitely generated $A$-module and its projective cover. If I know that the annihilator $Ann(M)\neq 0$, is it generally true that $Ann(P(M))\neq 0$ ?

What I have tried is the following: Assume $Ann(P(M))=0$. Since $P(M)$ is projective, we know that it is then a progenerator of A. I'm trying to show that $M$ is then a generator of $A$, and consequently $Ann(M)=0$ which is a contradiction. However, what I already can prove (using an argument) is that only simple $A$-modules are homomorphic images of copies of $M$. Is this sufficient to deduce that $M$ is a generator of $A$ ?

I will thank any comments.

Comment: Crossposted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447577/annihilator-of-a-projective-cover)

Comment: Please do not cross post on MO.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, let $A=k[t]/(t^2)$, a two-dimensional algebra over a field $k$. Let $M$ be the one-dimensional simple module $A/(t)$. Then $P(M)\cong A$, so $\operatorname{Ann}(P(M))=0$ but $\operatorname{Ann}(M)=(t)$.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.